# UIButton Animation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I'm working with XCode9 and Swift 4. I am using these button templates as placeholders for my application design. I'm trying to figure out how to make the button animate like the picture. Or is there a way to animate each picture into a single button press? Thanks!

[image: Button Image]

Comment: How do you hover over a button in iOS?

Comment: Meant highlight haha, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done by implementing a different UIImage for these three states of the button

1- Orange ----> .normal

2- Hover ----> .highlighted

3- Pressed ----> touch down

off course the 3 images design will be different to reflect the bottom part of the image that makes the user feel that the button can be compressed